# What is a type that describes polymorphic variants surrounded by square brackets?

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code:

```ml
type 'a t =
  [ `With_degree_bound of
    'a Or_infinity.t Dlog_plonk_types.Poly_comm.With_degree_bound.t
  | `Without_degree_bound of
    'a Dlog_plonk_types.Poly_comm.Without_degree_bound.t ]
```

I'm wondering why there are square brackets around the tags

Comment: [Polymorphic Variants in OCaml](https://ocaml.org/manual/polyvariant.html). Mind the `\`` in the patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a type that describes polymorphic variants surrounded by square brackets?

It *is* a polymorphic variant type. We define a polymorphic variant type as,

```
[ `C1 | `C2 | ... ]
```

and can use it anywhere where a type expression is expected, e.g.,

```
let x : [`C1 | `C2] = `C1
```

Or to define a type alias,

```
type c1or2 = [`C1 | `C2`]
```

in your case `'a t` is a type alias for a much verbose type expression,

```
type 'a t =
  [ `With_degree_bound of
    'a Or_infinity.t Dlog_plonk_types.Poly_comm.With_degree_bound.t
  | `Without_degree_bound of
    'a Dlog_plonk_types.Poly_comm.Without_degree_bound.t ]
```

so that whenever you need to refer the above type you can just use `'a t`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to ask the language designers for any kind of definitive answer, but a few considerations that come to mind:

1. Polymorphic variants are structural, meaning that the type definitions can occur in type annotations, not just in type declarations, and therefore have to be distinct and contained from all other elements that can occur there.
2. Polymorphic variants are subtype polymorphic (hence the name), meaning that they can unify with types that are "bigger" or "smaller", and can therefore be annotated with either `>` or `<` to denote that.
3. Other kinds of brackets are already sued for other purposes in type definitions. Parentheses are used for grouping, curly brackets are used for records, angle brackets are used for objects. And so square brackets seem like a good choice to reduce overloading.

I'm sure there are many other considerations as well, but just these three makes a good case for using square brackets I think.

Comment: I *think* the question was “what does this syntax denote” rather than “why has this syntax been designed like that”.

Comment: The question title already mentions polymorphic variants, and the question body explicitly asks "why there are square brackets around the tags". But yeah, could be \*shrug\*.

Comment: Oh, perhaps the `What` in title should have been a `Why`? @David 天宇 Wong, could you clarify?

Comment: it's more of a "what am I looking at" :D but interesting answer nonetheless!